# auto-update my table using phpmyadmin trigger or bash script

Tags: auto-update

This is what I want to do...
1. read table
2. if `UPDATE_REQ` is not equal to `0000-00-00 00:00:00` or `NULL`
   then
     do move data from infonew to infomain
     do delete data from infonew
     do reset value of update_req to null
3. else end script

TABLE looks like this...

> shopname | infomain | infonew | date
>
> ABC | Location | New location | 2014-01-01 10:00:00
>
> XYZ | Location | Null | 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Please help me which is the best solution (Create a trigger in phpmyadmin, create bash script or create php script)

Thanks! I am looking forward to your response.

Comment: Is it a ONE time conversion or it must be like a service, repeating every X seconds?

Comment: Hi Jorge, thanks for your response. It would be better if the script will run automatically when the UPDATE_REQ data is updated. OR maybe it is also OK if it will run every 12MN. I hope you could help me. Thanks!